# Finding potential to a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$F= (2x+4x^3 \arctan y+yz ,3y^2+\frac{x^{4}}{1+y^{2}}+xz,4z^{3}+xy)$
I need to find potential to this vector field.

$f = z^{4}+xyz+g(x,y)$ (integrating with respect to $z$)

How to continue from here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g = y^{3}+x^{4}arctany+h(x)$ ( integrating with respect to y) 
but $f = z^{4}+xyz+y^{3}+x^{4}arctany+h(x)$

taking partial with respect to x and you find that $h'(x) = 2x$